# How do you use a custom framework with Objects in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, object, oop

I have just started a new job out of uni and I am learn OO PHP we have a custom framework where I work and my boss was talking about teaching me how to use JQuery with objects. I am also unsure whether he means objects from PHP classes or whether JQuery has its own object of some type. I am not sure exactly what he means by this. Is there anywhere I can find out how to do this in a general sense? My boss is in a meeting today and I would like to get cracking.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have to be javascript objects. You might want to have a look at some resources for JSON.

Comment: Ah yes he did mention JSON I think. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Only way you could interconnect PHP and jQuery is AJAX. For example, `load` some .php file, which some object from your framework. :)

Comment: Ah ok I know about AJAX. So I think he must be talking about setting up classes in JQuery.